# Amplification effect of retweets on uncertainty

Tags: confidence-interval, lognormal-distribution, uncertainty, weighted-data, weighted-sampling

Consider you are scoring tweets for tone based on some *sentiment analysis* implementation. Each tweet has hypothetically a 90% chance of being correctly scored, while 10% get it wrong for whatever reason eg sarcasm, irony.  If you have 10,000 unique tweets, the resulting aggregate tone score for the set might be reasonably reliable, with mis-scorings largely cancelling out.  If however the set includes say 4,000 **retweets** of one viral tweet, then there is a 10% chance that the 40% of the results are very wrong, which will lead to very misleading conclusions.  If successful tweets tend to employ sarcasm and irony more often then the risk might be much higher.

Is there any scholarship on the evaluation of uncertainty / confidence intervals in the context where there is a factor like the presence of retweets, or in other words a dataset that is weighted by a log distribution?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would include retweets (in other words, duplicated observations) in your dataset?

Comment: Retweeting is endorsement in majority of cases, so if you are doing sentiment analysis they are important reflection of the tone used by a segment of the platform on the topic to hand. Omission is possible but will lose that insight.

Comment: But more to the point, the question is not about my current work but a question about estimation of uncertainty in this context :)

Comment: Maybe you could use the number of retweets as a feature instead of duplicating the observations, but I guess you already thought of that. Interesting question anyway. There's some work on the bias introduced by duplicates in survey data: https://ojs.ub.uni-konstanz.de/srm/article/view/7149 but obviously it's not in a NLP context, so not entirely sure if it applies to your situation, and their simulations are nowhere near thousands of duplicates. Hopefully someone else will give you a more helpful answer!

Comment: Can you provide rough numbers on the distribution of number of retweets, eg two of the mean, median, mode, sd for the lognormal distribution? And how would you estimate the fraction of unretweeted tweets from the lognornal distribution: is it  the probability of $x<\frac12$, $ x<1$, $x<\frac32$, $x<2$, or something else?